# Matrix-matrix multiplication between A and B, with A a random matrix

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a special matrix-matrix multiplication (`AxB`) in CUDA, where `A` is a random `MxM` matrix and `B` is `MxN` matrix. In following code, `M` is just `2000` but in practical case, it will be replaced with big number so to give more than `2GB` matrix for `A`. Actually, all elements of `A` will be random and limited to some range so will be generated by a randomize function.

I have written the code below in which each element of `A` is randomly randomly picked up from an array so the original `AxB` will be modified as a vector of length `M` multiplied with `B`. Here is how I write my code but it seems that it doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cusp/complex.h>

using namespace std;

#define M 2000
#define N 300

typedef cusp::complex<double> Complex;

__global__ void MVult(Complex* ad, Complex* bd, Complex* cd, int m1, int n1, int n2) 
{
  int x = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  int y = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

  if(x < n2 && y < m1) 
  {   
    Complex sum = Complex(0.0, 0.0);
    int ridx = (rand()%(M-1)); // here I randomize the starting ridx 
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++) sum += ad[ridx + i] * bd[i * n2 + x];
    cd[y * n2 + x] = v;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector< Complex > _A(2*M+1);
  std::vector< Complex > _B(M*N);
  Complex *A, *B, *C;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&A, (2*M+1)*sizeof(Complex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&B, M*N*sizeof(Complex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&C, M*N*sizeof(Complex));

  for (int i=0; i<2*M+1; i++) _A[i] = Complex((double)i, (double)i);
  for (int i=0; i<M*N; i++) _B[i] = Complex(1.0, 0.0);

  cudaMemcpy( A, &_A[0], (2*M+1)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
  cudaMemcpy( B, &_B[0], (M*N)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  dim3 block(32, 32);           
  dim3 grid((N+31)/32, (M+31)/32);

  MVult<<<grid, block>>>(A, B, C, M, M, N);
  cudaMemcpy(&_B[0], &C[0], (M*N)*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(A);
  cudaFree(B);
  cudaFree(C);

  return 0;
}
```

I try to use CPU loop to loop it `M` times and each time run vector and matrix multiplication (done in CUDA), but it is too slow. I am looking for a faster way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be slow for two main reasons:

1. In the way you are constructing matrix `A`, you are randomly accessing global memory, so preventing coalesced accesses;
2. As pointed out by @talonmies in his comment below, you are implementing your own matrix-vector multiplication routine, which will be surely slower than highly optimized routines as `cuBLAS`.

To speed-up your code, instead of using your `__global__` function `MVult`, you could/should use

1. `cuRAND` to fill the matrix `A` with random numbers;
2. `cuBLAS` to perform the matrix multiplication between `A` and `B`, and, in particular, `cublasCgemm()` for single precision complex calculations.

If matrix `A` is too large, then you can try to divide the computation of `A*B` into smaller tiles and then using the batch functionality of `cuBLAS` (using `cublasSetStream()`) to try achieving concurrent execution using CUDA streams.

You might also wish to take a look at the following example using also thrust:

[Matrix multiplication on GPU using CUDA with CUBLAS, CURAND and Thrust](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/05/31/matrix-multiplication-cuda-cublas-curand-thrust/)

As also suggested by @talonmies, you might also wish to *rethink* your approach. For example, if `A` is a random matrix, then `A*B` will be random too. Is there the possibility to exploit the statistics of `A` and possibly a priori knowledge on `B` to construct the matrix `A*B` directly by a stochastic approach without the need to using matrix multiplications?

Comment: I tried cuBLAS and cublasZgemm alreayd, it still too slow. I don't know much about cublasSetStream, is there any example I can follow? I only see the document online and didn't see a complete example

Comment: @user12854197: you won't be able to write a faster routine than what is already in CUBLAS. if Zgemm from CUBLAS is too slow, then you need a  to rethink your approach to the problem, not try and write your own complex gemm kernel

Comment: @user1285419 What do you mean by "too slow"? Is it slower than your own approach? What is the execution time you expect to multiply `A` and `B`, when `A` is a `2Gb` matrix, i.e., a matrix of about `20000x20000` elements in floating point precision?

Comment: @user1285419 talonmies is also suggesting to rethink your approach. If `A` is a random matrix, then also `A*B` will be random too. Is there the possibility to exploit the statistics of `A` and possibly _a priori_ knowledge on `B` to construct the matrix `A*B` directly by a stochastic approach without the need to using matrix multiplications?